# Is an explicit CacheManager bean definition mandatory when using Spring Boot + Spring Cache?

Tags: spring-boot, spring-cache

From documentation Spring Boot uses ConcurrentMapCacheManager as CacheManager implementation by default if we don't define own CacheManager bean definition. But I keep getting 'No qualifying bean of type 'org.springframework.cache.CacheManager' available' error eventhough spring-boot-starter-cache and @EnableCaching is there.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Best regards,

SetNug

Comment: Do you have an example repo reproducing the the issue you could share? Also be careful if you have more than 1 caching provider on the classpath at a time (e.g. Redis + Ehcache).

Answer (score 2):

Short answer... NO.

I suspect you are having problems while (integration) testing? If so, then you probably need to declare the appropriate "test slice annotation", that is `@AutoConfigureCache`; see [Javadoc](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/api/org/springframework/boot/test/autoconfigure/core/AutoConfigureCache.html).

To demonstrate, I created a simple example with a [test class](https://github.com/jxblum/stackoverflow-questions-answers/blob/master/spring-boot-default-caching/src/test/java/io/stackoverflow/question/answers/spring/boot/caching/tests/SpringBootDefaultCachingIntegrationTests.java) contained in this [module](https://github.com/jxblum/stackoverflow-questions-answers/tree/master/spring-boot-default-caching) of my SO [repository](https://github.com/jxblum/stackoverflow-questions-answers). You must declare the `@AutoConfigureCache` annotation in configuration (see [here](https://github.com/jxblum/stackoverflow-questions-answers/blob/master/spring-boot-default-caching/src/test/java/io/stackoverflow/question/answers/spring/boot/caching/tests/SpringBootDefaultCachingIntegrationTests.java#L95-L98)) even if your test is a `@SpringBootTest`.

As Spring Boot's [documentation describes](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/features.html#features.testing.spring-boot-applications.autoconfigured-tests), all of Spring Boot's *auto-configuration* (which is quite extensive) can be a bit much for testing. As such, none of Spring Boot's *auto-configuration* is enabled by default. Therefore, you must explicitly enable what you want, or, alternatively, you can declare that you want Spring Boot's entire *auto-configuration* enabled, by replacing the `@AutoConfigureCache` annotation declaration with Spring Boot's `@EnableAutoConfiguration` annotation instead.

You are correct that Spring Boot will auto-configure a "Simple" caching provider (i.e. the `ConcurrentMapCacheManager`, or in other words, a Spring `CacheManager` implementation backed by a `java.util.concurent.ConcurrentHashMap`; see [here](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/io.html#io.caching.provider.simple)) when no other cache provider implementation (e.g Redis) is present or explicitly declared.

However, Spring Boot *auto-configuration* is only in effect when your Spring Boot application is an "application", which I have shown [here](https://github.com/jxblum/stackoverflow-questions-answers/blob/master/spring-boot-default-caching/src/main/java/io/stackoverflow/question/answers/spring/boot/caching/app/SpringBootDefaultCachingApplication.java).

Of course, it is also `true` that if your `@SpringBootApplication` annotated class is found (in the classpath component-scan) by your test as [described](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/features.html#features.testing.spring-boot-applications.detecting-configuration), then it will also enable caching without any explicit annotations, such as, no need to explicitly declare the `@AutoConfigureCache` test slice annotation, even.

> NOTE: In my example, I deliberately did not package the source according to the [suggested structure](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/using.html#using.structuring-your-code). So, if I were to replace the `@AutoConfigureCache` annotation declaration [in my test configuration](https://github.com/jxblum/stackoverflow-questions-answers/blob/master/spring-boot-default-caching/src/test/java/io/stackoverflow/question/answers/spring/boot/caching/tests/SpringBootDefaultCachingIntegrationTests.java#L96) with `@Import(SpringBootDefaultCachingApplication.class)` and comment out [this assertion](https://github.com/jxblum/stackoverflow-questions-answers/blob/master/spring-boot-default-caching/src/main/java/io/stackoverflow/question/answers/spring/boot/caching/app/SpringBootDefaultCachingApplication.java#L64) from the application class, then the test would also pass. Using the `@Import` annotation in this way works similarly as if the test class and application class were in the same package, or the application class were in a parent package relative to the test class.

1 last tip... you can always enable Spring Boot [debugging](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/features.html#features.spring-application.startup-failure) (see Baeldung's [blog](https://www.baeldung.com/spring-boot-auto-configuration-report)) to see what *auto-configuration* is applied while running your application, or even while running tests.

Comment: Thank you for your lengthy explanation. You're correct that I'm having this problem during integration test. Adding `@EnableAutoConfiguration` solves it, but `@AutoConfigureCache` seems better since the test's target is cache. Also it turns out that spring-boot-starter-cache starter is not needed.

Comment: The `spring-boot-starter-cache` dependency is not needed only if you already transitively pulled in the `spring-context-support` dependency from the core Spring Framework somehow. See here: https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/blob/main/spring-boot-project/spring-boot-starters/spring-boot-starter-cache/build.gradle#L9.  The `spring-context[-support]` module(s) is where Spring's Cache Abstraction lives. Glad you are back on track.